# How to get confirm message on Url.Action?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Here I want to get the confirm message when delete button is clicked with out using any jquery for which i have used onclick on `Html.Action`as below

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete","StudentDetails", new { id=item.StudentId}, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are sure wants to delete?');" } )'"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><br>
```

But it shows an error saying `"cannot convert from '<anonymous type: int id>'to 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary'>"` on `new { id=item.StudentId}` and `Cannot convert from '<anonymous type:string onclick>'to 'string'`

Any Help will be great

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to split this out.

Add the URL to a data attribute, something like

`<button data-url="@Url.Action("Delete","StudentDetails", new { id=item.StudentId})" onclick="ConfirmDeletion()"></button>`

Then onclick can call a javascript function

```
function ConfirmDeletion()
{
  var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
  if (x) {
      var url = this.getAttribute('data-url')
      location.href= = url;
}
```

}

I haven't tested this but I think its simpler and clearer